# bootstrap-date_picker conjunction responsive html5 type date for iphone view

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I build an iphone friendly view using bootstrap 2.3.2 and bootstrap-date_picker
bootstrap-date_picker works well unless view is rendered on iphone.
i would like to have standart html5 tag **type='date'** without datepicker behaviour for **@media (max-width: 767px)**

I'm wondering how to implement such behaviour.

my view:

```
<input class="string date_picker optional" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy" data-date-language="ru" id="ride_trip_date" name="ride[trip][date]" type="text">
```

my js:

```
$("input.date_picker").datepicker()
```

i can't make second partial with **.visible-phone** because this input is array of nested attributes for my model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia):

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {
  $("input.date_picker").datepicker();
}
```